# magento attributes values in additional information tab in popup

Tags: php, magento

I want to display additional information tab content in magento product page in a POPUP. Basically I want a popup that will display all attribute values for that product in a popup linked to a button. I was able to create POPUP where I am able to get CURRENT product but not able to get all other attribute values, etc. Can somebody help with get this information in popup. I am not a programmer and may be I am wrong in my approach.

Basically I want to know how to pass the product ID and attribute details to POPUP template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to load produt module

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
```

Try to load all eav attribute of product type
        $

```
attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->getItems();

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
            echo $attribute->getAttributecode();
            echo '<br>';
            echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();

    echo $product->getData($attribute->getAttributecode());
        }
```